¿Cómo especificar a Pytest que se está haciendo una simulación de consulta a base de datos?
Presentación del caso:
Creé una clase para simular data como resultado de una consulta a base de datos. ¿Cómo especifico a Pytest que es una simulación de consulta a una base de datos?

Deseo saber que malas prácticas puedo estar cometiendo.

Clase a ser testeada:
    class DataXY:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.__x = 0
            self.__y = 0
            self.__data = []
    
        def setDataXY(self, data:list=[], cant:int=0):
            self.__data = []
            val = True
            if (len(data)>0):
                for i in data:
                    if(type(i) == type({})):
                        keys = []
                        for ii in i.keys():
                            keys.append(ii)
                        if(len(keys)!=2):
                            val = False
                            break
                    else:
                        val = False
                        break
                if(val):
                    self.__data = data
            i=0
            while(i<cant):
                self.__data.append({"x":i,"y":i})
                i+=int(1)
    
        def getDataXY(self):
            return self.__data
    
        def insertDataXY(self, x:int, y:int)->object:
            self.setX(x)
            self.setY(y)
            reg = {
                    'x':self.getX(),
                    'y':self.getY()
                }
            self.__data.append(reg)
            return reg
    
        def updateDataXYByInd(self, ind:int, x:int, y:int)->None:
            self.updateXByInd(ind, x)
            self.updateYByInd(ind, y)
            return self.__data[ind]
    
        def updateXByInd(self, ind:int, x:int)->object:
            self.__data[ind]['x'] = x
            return self.__data[ind]
    
        def updateYByInd(self, ind:int, y:int)->object:
            self.__data[ind]['y'] = y
            return self.__data[ind]
    
        def getDataXYByInd(self, ind)->int:
            return self.__data[ind]
        
        def getXByInd(self, ind)->int:
            return self.__data[ind]['x']
    
        def getYByInd(self, ind)->int:
            return self.__data[ind]['y']
    
        def setX(self, x)->int:
            self.__x = x
    
        def getX(self)->int:
            return self.__x
        
        def setY(self, y)->int:
            self.__y = y
    
        def getY(self)->int:
            return self.__y
        
        def deleteYXByInd(self, ind:int)->object:
            try:
                res = self.__data[ind]
                del self.__data[ind]
                return res
            except:
                return {}

Objeto de la clase:
    [
        {"x":0, "y":0},
        {"x":1, "y":1},
        ...
    ]

Estos son los test que he realizado:
    from practices.data.dataXY import DataXY
    
    dataXY = DataXY()
    
    def test_setDataXY_01():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":1}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == data
    
    def test_setDataXY_02():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2},{"x":2, "y":3}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == data
    
    def test_setDataXY_03():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}]
        cant=0
        dataXY.setDataXY(data, cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == data
    
    def test_setDataXY_04():
        data=[{"x":33, "y":44}]
        cant=1
        dataXY.setDataXY(data, cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == [{"x":33, "y":44},{"x":0, "y":0}]
    
    def test_setDataXY_05():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}]
        cant=-10
        dataXY.setDataXY(data, cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == data
    
    def test_setDataXY_06():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}, 1]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_07():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}, "1"]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_08():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}, {}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_09():
        data=[{"x":1, "y":2}, []]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_10():
        data=[1, {"x":1, "y":2}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_11():
        data=["1", {"x":1, "y":2}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_12():
        data=[{}, {"x":1, "y":2}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_13():
        data=[[], {"x":1, "y":2}]
        dataXY.setDataXY(data)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_14():
        cant=-1
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_15():
        cant=0
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == []
    
    def test_setDataXY_16():
        cant=1
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=cant)
        assert dataXY.getDataXY() == [{"x":0, "y":0}]
    
    def test_getDataXYByInd():
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=100)
        assert dataXY.getDataXYByInd(3) == {"x":3, "y":3}
    
    def test_setGetX():
        dataXY.setX(2)
        assert dataXY.getX() == 2
    
    def test_setGetY():
        dataXY.setY(3)
        assert dataXY.getY() == 3
    
    def test_getXByInd():
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=100)
        assert dataXY.getXByInd(33) == 33
    
    def test_getYByInd():
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=100)
        assert dataXY.getYByInd(22) == 22
    
    def test_insertDataXY():
        x, y = 11, 22
        assert dataXY.insertDataXY(x, y) == {"x":11, "y":22}
    
    def test_updateDataXYByInd():
        ind, x, y = 33, 44, 55
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=100)
        assert dataXY.updateDataXYByInd(ind, x, y) == {"x":44, "y":55}
    
    def test_updateXByInd():
        ind, x, y, xn = 33, 44, 55, 66
        dataXY.updateDataXYByInd(ind, x, y)
        assert dataXY.updateXByInd(ind, xn) == {"x":66, "y":55}
    
    def test_updateYByInd():
        ind, x, y, yn = 33, 77, 88, 99
        dataXY.updateDataXYByInd(ind, x, y)
        assert dataXY.updateYByInd(ind, yn) == {"x":77, "y":99}
    
    def test_deleteYXByInd():
        dataXY.setDataXY(cant=100)
        assert dataXY.deleteYXByInd(99) == {"x":99, "y":99}

Ejecución en consola:

Fuentes:
Repositorio del código:
https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/pytestGetstarted
Documentación de Pytest:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.2.x/getting-started.html#get-started

"simulación de consulta a una base de datos" no entiendo esto.. los test son justamente simulaciones.. se que python hace muchas cosas raras a veces... pero es necesario aclarar eso en los test?

Una alternativa es usar una versión de prueba de la base de datos. La puedes recargar antes de cada corrida para partir siempre del mismo ambiente.
